# Error when importing a jar

Tags: android, jar

//**this is a issue of android when import  jar into project,and under is the logcat display:
Can you help me??**

```
06-25 02:52:05.870: I/dalvikvm(769): Failed resolving Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl; interface 3262 'Lorg/w3c/dom/events/EventTarget;'
06-25 02:52:05.870: W/dalvikvm(769): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl;' failed
06-25 02:52:05.870: W/dalvikvm(769): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/ChildNode; (2093)
06-25 02:52:05.870: W/dalvikvm(769): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/ChildNode;' failed
06-25 02:52:05.870: W/dalvikvm(769): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/ParentNode; (2046)
06-25 02:52:05.870: W/dalvikvm(769): Link of class 'Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/ParentNode;' failed
06-25 02:52:05.870: W/dalvikvm(769): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl; (2104)
```

wait your solve!!

Answer (score 0):

The jar file you are linking to needs to be in the libs folder and/or marked for export. You can mark for export in Eclipse by right-clicking your project and selecting **Properties>Java Build Path>Order and Export** then selecting the checkbox of the jar you have imported.

Comment: yes,I do it that like you say,but it is not the solve.BTW,My IDE is Android IDE (just is Eclipse)Android Developer Tools

Build: v22.0.1-685705

Comment: Cool. If you're satisfied with my answer, I would appreciate an upvote and answer selection :)

Comment: en.I import the jars is nekohtml.jar,xalan.jar,xercesImpl.jar.Its has a order when compile and run in android VM ??

Comment: You don't have to worry about order so much: just make sure you have them **all** marked for export. I'm 99% sure that is the problem here.

Comment: can you give a emaill adress (gmail) to me ,I send the src of my project to you.And ...

Answer (score 0):

The jar or library file while you add to a project, need to be in the same workspace.